# Booting Kali Linux On To A Windows 8.1 Tablet~

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, kali-linux, bootable-media, tablet

I am having some trouble booting kali onto my tablet, now my goal is a simple portable penetration testing machine that I can carry on the go.

hmm where to start.

Ok so I have created the bootable usb it has kali on it, now windows 8.1 tablet is awkward and so I can't do the regular f2 on start up and go to the BIOS, instead I have to go to settings in the tablet and hit "change advanced start-up options" so then it restarts the tablet and prompts me with the following options

Continue
Use a Device (usb drive,network connection or windows recovery cd)
TroubleShoot

So the first thing i thought well use a device of course :) then it prompts me with

EFI USB DEVICE

so then I click this and it reboots, it then attempts to boot but then it says

"system doesn't have any usb boot option. Please select another in boot manager menu"

hmm so I assume either my machine is not capable of doing this or I need to disable something (I have disable quick boot already).

so I go all the way back to the options from before which were

Continue,

Use a Device (usb drive,network connection or windows recovery cd),

TroubleShoot

I click trouble shoot and decide to enter advanced options - UEFI Firmware Settings, then it restarts and provides the following options.

Continue
Boot Manager
Device Management
Boot From File
Secure Boot Option
SCU

looked at EFI Boot Order comes up with

windows boot manage 
Internal EFI Shell

Ive tried all options but no success :(

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

(quick Edit: I also receive this message when attempting to boot directly from the ISO file.

this program does not support windows 6.2.9200 sp0 yet)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Kali Live USB disk in the USB 3 port on the Surface Pro, and head back to the Settings menu on the Charm Bar. Navigate back to the General PC settings and boot into Advanced Startup. Tap the icon with the USB stick and the DVD labeled Use a Device one the Surface has booted into the Advanced settings.

From here, you will be presented with a list of available boot options that are currently detected. Your USB disk will be clearly labeled in the list, and when you tap on the icon for your drive the Surface will reboot. From this point, you will no longer be in Windows, as you will be booting from the USB drive.

When the Surface reboots, you’ll be greeted by impossibly small white text on a black background. The GRUB menu is prompting you to either install Kali linux or boot from the Live USB and try it out for yourself before you install. As a rule, you should always try it out before you blow away your perfectly functional OS.

Personally I do not recommend kali linux as a starting operating system. Try using mint etc. The same process will work